# Why does the eigenvector have to be positive here?

Tags: coding-theory, symbolic-computation

The following Pictures are taken from "Symbolic Dynamics and Coding" by Lind and Marcus.!
[image: 1]

---

[image: 2]

Can you tell me why it is so important that the eigenvector $v$ is positive? 
Where exactly is this needed above? Or asked more concretly:

Why would be happen to inequality (4-2-1) if the eigenvector $v$ would not be positive?

With Greetings

Comment: Couldn't you *at least* have rotated the second picture?

Comment: I tried but it is always showe this way, sorry!

Comment: @Git Gud Thank you for editing

Comment: @mathfemi No problem. Where is it needed? Right at the bottom of page 106 it is needed. I didn't read past that.

Comment: @GitGud Ok, but . . . why is it necessary that $(Av)_I>0$ resp. $\lambda v_I>0$ resp. $\lambda >0$?

Comment: @mathfemi $A$ is non-negative because it is an adjacency matrix and since $v$ is positive all of its entries greater than zero, therefore there is an entry $I$ in $Av$, denoted by $(Av)_I$ that is greater than zero and since $Av=\lambda v$, the conclusions follow.

Comment: @GitGud That's not the point, because I understood that. My problem is where in the following (from p. 107 on) I need that $v$ is positive. I do not see why this is so important.

Comment: You are dividing by the minimal component $c$. If that is not known to be positive, then you might need to revert the inequalities. Or may be I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think you did not misunderstand. :-) Indeed my problem is to see why the final inequality (4-2-1) would not hold if the Eigenvector $v$ would not be positive.